# Solr Support for wildcard in facet.prefix

Tags: solr

I have a system which has huge number of facet values on Country name. So the countries can be USA, United State, Canada etc

Now I wanted facets to be custom sorted. By default solr supports either count based sorting or alphabetic sorting. However I did not wanted sorting in this manner. I wanted to have a custom sort such that also USA variations comets at a top, then europe, then asia and so on.

For this I have written a tokenizer which reads a text file and generates token like this

0001_usa
0002_united state

So basically I prefix my sort sequence and then sort on alphabetic order. I then remove the prefix while displaying on UI. So far it works great. Now since the number of facets are huge, I also want a search feature with auto suggest. So for example if a user types "u" I should be able to display all countries starting with "u" in the type ahead. I was using facet.prefix earlier for this but after my custom token it would not work since I prefix 000x to the token. Also facet.prefix does not seem to support wild card. So how can I implement this type ahead? Any other way to support custom sorting in Solr. I do not want to get all the data on client and sort since its huge.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You easily achieve this by indexing the country names in an additional field, with the right handlers for autosuggest.

You could have something like **country_sort** where you put your prefixed values like before (001_usa, 0002_united state) and a **country_autosugest** field where you put the plain values (usa, united states).

Then query on country_autosugest and sort on country_sort. This way you can also return the value of country_autosuggest, no need to process the string at display time.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. may be I would explain a UI bit so it gets clear. At the UI we display the first 50 facet and then show the search box. Now when a user search we need to apply it as a filter and show that filter selected also. Now having two fields with different token the applied filter would not match with the facet field since those have prefix . Hence a two field approach would not work since we need to apply filter after a type ahead search and also show the applied filter on the UI

Comment: If you haven't sorted this out already, can you paste the relevant bits from your schema.xml and the solr query/select URL? It would be clearer if you continued your example with 0001_usa, 0002_united state with the use case you just described.